# Is there a way t change the Windows Scale Factor in Python

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

Is there a way to change the Windows Scale Factor with python?
My Tkinter Applications are designed for 1920x1280 and a Scale Factor of 100%
But some of my clients use my applications on a Tablet with a Scale Factor of 150% and my Tkinter Windows are too big in this environment.

I think the easiest way to make my Applications usable on these devices is to set the Scale Factor manually to 100% before i start to redesign my whole GUI.

Comment: You can put all of your widgets in a canvas then zoom in/out that canvas. To detect the scale factor you can use `<any widget>.winfo_screenheight()` and `<any widget>.winfo_screenwidth()`.

Comment: I have all of my Widgets within a mainframe. You mean that i should put that Mainframe into a canvas and scale it with the canvas scale method? I tried this, but a don't get this to work

Answer (score 0):

I found that when I add

```
from pywinauto import Desktop
```

at the top of my source code, the user interface automatically scales.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the window to fit the size of a device, use the following:

```
window.state("zoomed")
```

This maximizes your window.
If you want to just get the screen width and screen height of a device, use:

```
width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
height = window.winfo_screenheight()
```

Then you can use these to set the geometry of the window:

```
window.geometry("%dx%d" % (width, height))
```

Comment: Yes this resizes the window. But Font sizes and positions and everything stays the same. `from pywinauto import Desktop` resizes the whole interface...  Works like a charm

Comment: Oh, I thought you only wanted the window resolution to be changed. Thanks for introducing me to `from pywinauto import Desktop`, though! I've never heard of it before